# Writing a cookie with different host name

Tags: php, cookies

I have been facing the problem in setting a cookie to the client browser with different host name . Is there any work around?

Comment: What is your code, is it not working or are you receiving an error?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Being able to do so would be a massive security hole.

Comment: inf act it writes the cookie but with changed hostname / domain where script is hosted